# an error 3013 thrown when writing a file Adobe AIR

Tags: air, file-writing

I'm trying to write/create a JSON file from a AIR app, I'm trying not so show a 'Save as' dialogue box.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var fileDetails:Object = CreativeMakerJSX.getFileDetails();
var fileName:String = String(fileDetails.data.filename);
var path:String = String(fileDetails.data.path);
var f:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath( path );
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(f, FileMode.WRITE );
stream.writeUTFBytes( jsonToExport );
stream.close();
```

The problem I'm having is that I get a 'Error 3013. File or directory in use'. The directory/path is gathered from a Creative Suite Extension I'm building, this path is the same as the FLA being developed in CS that the Extension is being used with.

So I'm not sure if the problem is that there are already files in the directory I'm writing the JSON file to?

Do I need to add a timer in order to close the stream after a slight delay, giving some time to writing the file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I re-wrote how the file was written, no longer running into this issue.

Comment: Post the code you used to fix this issue; I'm running into it in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up some `trace()` commands?  I would need to know what the values of the `String` variables are, and the `f.url`.

Can you read from the file that you are trying to write to, or does nothing work?

Where is `CreativeMakerJSX.getFileDetails()` coming from?  Is it giving you data about a file that is in use?

And from Googling around, this seems like it may be a bug.  Try setting up a listener for when you are finished, if you have had the file open previously.

Comment: Hi,I have actually fixed the issue. I had to re-write how I was creating/writing the file. I should have marked this question  as closed, sorry.