# Adobe Air FileStream Error #3013: File or directory is in use

Tags: file-io, air

Did a search on google and here
[an error 3013 thrown when writing a file Adobe AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588493/an-error-3013-thrown-when-writing-a-file-adobe-air)
but haven't found a solution yet

Using the Filestream class to simply open and write a file to the ApplicationStorage directory

This works fine on Mac-OSX. But when in Windows I get the following error

```
Error: Error #3013: File or directory is in use.
    at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()
```

I've checked permissions both on the actual file and enclosing directory and that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Can anyone suggest a solution or troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything pointed to security-permissions issue, but double checked and permissions are fine

After much googling and head scratching came across this post which solved the problem
http://www.davidmillington.net/news/453/62/ActionScript-3---Error-%233013%3A-File-or-directory-is-in-use./

A slight delay is needed BEFORE using the FileStream class to open, write, close.
Again, Windows only!

Comment: "Add a small delay" to fix an asynchronous problem is never a good idea.  It can simply make the problem appear at different times.  AIR allows both synchronous (via `FileStream.open`) and asynchronous (via `FileStream.openAsync` and `URLLoader` with local-file URLs) access to files.  One solution would be to use synchronous access everywhere, another would be to handle async error conditions.  The linked blog suggests adding a delay to solve the problem, and also suggests code adding an event listener without removing it, both of which are Bad Ideas(TM).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i solved it by adding an event listener to my file stream.

```
private function someFunction():void
{
   _writeFileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onWriteFileStreamComplete);               
   _writeFileStream.close();
}

private function onWriteFileStreamComplete(e:Event):void
{
   //do the stuff you want to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in **File** class and I solved it like @raduanastase done but I didn't add **Event.CLOSE** as Event listener, i have added **Event.COMPLETE** as event listener and it is solved

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this problem and it was due to me opening more than one FileStream for the same file.  Just do a quick double-check to make sure you didn't do the same.  If that isn't your problem, the other answers should help.